# Maintaining Bootability of volumes in Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, bootable-media

What makes a volume bootable in Mac OS X?

I have backed up all the files on my bootable volume and I want to restore it back with bootability.

All the files required for booting is present in my new volume. Still volume is not booting. I could see it is appearing in System preference as bootable But when I boot computer simply turns off.

Do I need to do anything to make it bootable after restoring file bootable files.

I had used rsync to backup all files.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Carbon Copy Cloner http://www.bombich.com/ to clone the drive.

This page on their site http://help.bombich.com/kb/troubleshooting/what-makes-a-volume-bootable also has a very detailed explanation as to what is required to be a bootable volume.